# Mostrar icono en un formulario segun el tipo utlizando TextInputEditText

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un formulario en mi app android, el cual lo hago dinamicamente y mi xml es el siguiente

```
com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/edtPassText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
app:errorTextAppearance="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/textEdit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    >

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
```

como hago para cambiar el **InputType** programaticamente a "text" o "textPassword" segun el tipo de campo, ya que tengo 3 campos, nombre, edad, contraseña, y lo que quiero esque en mi ultimo campo me aparezca el icono del ojo para poder mostrar/ocultar la contraseña.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes definir un icono en el `TextInputLayout` un icono mediante el atributo [app:startIconDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setStartIconDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edtPassText"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/myImage"
        ...
        ...
```

Si quieres incluso mostrar dos iconos, uno cuando se muestra el password y otro cuando lo oculta puedes usar el atributo `app:passwordToggleDrawable`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44190131/250260) de [sam.y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1519988/sham-y):

---

Crear un nuevo archivo drawable y nombrarlo como `show_password_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_black_18dp" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_off_black_18dp"/>
</selector>
```

y en tu layout, agregar el atributo `app:passwordToggleDrawable` en tu `TextInputLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutTextInput"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/show_password_selector"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextValue"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:inputType="text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Video de referencia: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dW0YIV0Z9qk